# It is possible to rewrite the following cycle using stream api or am I trying in vain?

Tags: java, java-stream

Main object:

```
public class Order {
    private Long orderId;
    ...
    private List<OrderAudit> auditList;
}
```

Item object of Order

```
public class OrderAudit {
    private Long orderId;
    ...
}
```

All orders

```
List<Order> orderList = orderDao.getOrderList(request);
```

All items

```
List<OrderAudit> allAudits = orderDao.getAllAudits();
```

There I try to find all audits of each order and set this list to order. Cycle:

```
for (Order order : orderList) {
    Long orderId = order.getOrderId();

    List<OrderAudit> orderAuditList = allAudits.stream()
                                               .filter(x-> x.getOrderId().equals(orderId))
                                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
    order.setAuditList(orderAuditList);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupingBy` to create map of `List<OrderAudit>` by `orderId`

```
Map<Long, List<OrderAudit>> orderAuditMap = allAudits.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OrderAudit::getOrderId));
```

If you want to preserve order of `OrderAudit`

```
Map<Long, List<OrderAudit>> orderAuditMap = allAudits.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i.getOrderId(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

Then get `List<OrderAudit>` by `orderId` from map and set in order using `forEach()`

```
orderList.stream().forEach(e -> e.setAuditList(orderAuditMap.get(e.getOrderId())));
```

Comment: To complete the solution and create a `List<Order>` in which each Order comprises of the `id` and corresponding `audits`, you could `stream` the `entrySet` after grouping and map to the `Order` object. Of course, if those `...` doesn't have a special meaning in the question. On the other hand using `peek` for operations other than debugging purpose isn't really reliable.

Comment: The original order of objects in both list is preserved after these operations?

Comment: For the first  part No but you can use `LinkedHashMap::new` and 2nd part yes

Comment: I updated the answer for preserved order of  `OrderAudit`

Comment: Maybe I put it wrong. I do not want to get the order of the groups, but a list of ```OrderAdit```s within the group. Is it possible? If this cannot be done, you will have to leave the loop. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: `LinkedHashMap::new` preserving insertation order for `OrderAditList` here you can check https://onlinegdb.com/ByPk7Ti5L